# Why aren't null values being converted to zero in my SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following expression:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!WellTestMeasLiqRate.Value) = true, 
     CDec(0), 
     IIf(Fields!WellTestMeasLiqRate.Value > 0,
         Fields!WellTestTotalGasRate.Value / Fields!WellTestMeasLiqRate.Value, 
         CDec(0)))
```

However it doesn't seem like null values are being caught by the IsNothing clause, and as a result this field is returning #VALUE when I produce the report.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the report showing `#VALUE` for all rows or just the NULL ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors such this, have to do with SSRS expression evaluation.

Use the following expression:

```
= Iif(  Fields!WellTestMeasLiqRate.Value <=0, Cdec(0),Fields!WellTestTotalGasRate.Value) 
/ 
Iif(  Fields!WellTestMeasLiqRate.Value <=0, Cdec(1),Fields!WellTestMeasLiqRate.Value)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SSRS validates both sides of the IFF expression. So if the denominator is 0 it will give you #error regardless of how many times you check.

What you need to do is place a small function in your report property code window

```
Public Function divide(Byval a As Decimal,Byval b As Decimal, Byval c As Decimal) As Decimal
'  Fix for divide by zero problem in VB
' calculates  a/b  and either returns result or c if b = 0 


if b = 0 then 
    return c 
else 
    return a/b 
end if 

end function
```

you then use this code to do the division

This is how you call the code

```
=code.divide(fields!numerator.value,Fields!denominator.Value,0.0)
```